# Arrays.deepEquals gives error for int[] but works for Integer[]

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, wrapper, autoboxing

I am using the following program in eclipse Kepler

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Mainn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int[] a = {1, 2};
        int[] b = {1, 2};

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(a, b));    
    }
}
```

It is giving me a compile time error about `int[]` arguments not being applicable for `Object[]` formal parameters. But the same program works fine when I use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` as the data type of the arrays `a` and `b`.

I am confused by this. According to [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) the compiler automatically autoboxes and unboxes between primitives and the wrapper classes so it should work here. But it isn't working. Why?

Comment: `Object` is not the superclass of `int`. Also `Integer` is the wrapper for `int`, but `Integer[]` is not the wrapper for `int[]`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But `Object` is superclass of `Integer`. Doesn't that apply?

Comment: `Integer` is an `Object`. `int` is **primitive** and not an `Object`.

Comment: `deepEquals(Object[] a1,Object[] a2)` can take arguments which are sub-types of `Object`. You can apply `instanceof` check to verify. `int` is not `Object` . Check Liskov Substitution principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for [subtyping arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3) are as follows, from the Java Language Specification, where `>` means *is a supertype*

> If S and T are both reference types, then `S[]` > `T[]` iff `S` > `T`.
>
> ...
>
> - If P is a primitive type, then:
>
>   - `Object >1 P[]`
>   - `Cloneable >1 P[]`
>   - `java.io.Serializable >1 P[]`

where `>1` means *is a direct supertype*.

In this case `S` is `Object` and `T` is `Integer`, So because `Integer` is a subtype of `Object` and therefore `Integer[]` is a subtype of `Object[]`, you can use it as an argument to a method that expects an `Object[]`.

However, for `int`, which is a primitive, `Object` is the supertype of `int[]` and therefore `int[]` cannot be used where an `Object[]` is expected.

The notion of wrapper classes doesn't apply here.

Comment: The link of Java Language Specification cleared a lot of things.

Comment: You should add that `>1` means `a direct supertype`.

Answer (score 4):

Auto-boxing applies to primitives like `int` (converted to `Integer`), but not to arrays - an object of type `int[]` is not automatically promoted to `Integer[]`

I don't have any specific sources for *why* this design choice was made, but there are a couple of points that seem relevant:

- `int[]` is already an object, whereas auto-boxing applies to primitives. Auto-boxing `int[]` (and other cases) would complicate the criteria for auto-boxing significantly (potentially resulting in unexpected behavior in some cases)
- Auto-boxing is not a zero-cost operation. Boxing `int[]` to `Integer[]` would mean creating a new array, then a new wrapper for every element in the array. In general Java tries to avoid doing costly operations implicitly.

Comment: Upvote for pointing out that `int[]` is an `Object`. That had skipped my mind. It cleared many things.